# ImportError: No module named deepmolecule.rdkit_utils

Tags: python, module

When I tried to python running, 
I got the error that 
ImportError: No module named deepmolecule.rdkit_utils

so I search about "deepmolecule.rdkit_utils" at google, but there are no exist about that module information.

How can I solve this problem?

This is importing modules in the python script file.

```py
import csv
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy

from deepmolecule.rdkit_utils import smile_to_fp
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import rdMolDescriptors
```

Comment: http://rdkit.org/docs/Install.html#cross-platform-under-anaconda-python-fastest-install

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the module got [renamed](https://github.com/HIPS/neural-fingerprint/commit/a903bd6dc51a6e126a3f5060645f80162690b3a5) to `neuralfingerprint` and is called `nfp` at [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/nfp/). Hence, you can install the module by running `pip install nfp` in your shell. Note that you might need to change the name of the module in your script.